# after groupby , how can i get the groupby columns?

Tags: python, data-analysis

this is my dataFrame:

```
data1   data2   key1    key2
0   -1.986321   -0.873129   a   one
1   0.169566    -1.503761   a   two
2   -1.019771   -0.095008   b   one
3   0.631865    -0.158880   b   two
4   -0.487121   0.643491    a   on
```

I use the statement:

```
a = df['data1'].groupby(df['key2']).sum()
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

then, I get a dataframe:

```
        data1
key2    
one 2.721642
two 0.238394
```

but,it is not that i want, i want a dataframe that can acces to key2.
when call key2 like this:

```
a['key2']
```

i get a KeyError: 'key2'
so,how i can get a dataframe like this ?

```
key2  data1
one 2.721642
two 0.238394
```

Comment: What dataframe do you want?

Comment: the dataframe that have corresponding column named key2

Comment: in other word, there is no error when i visit a['key2']

Comment: What is a['key2'] meant to return?

Comment: i found the answer that is use function of reset_index() , maybe i didn't explain my question clearly, the answer is too simple.....,but also thank you, when i was in dispirted , there is also a human want to help me.

Answer (score 0):

use the function of reset_index()
print(a):

```
      data1
key2    
one 2.721642
two 0.238394
```

print(a.reset_index())

```
    key2    data1
0   one 2.721642
1   two 0.238394
```

the difference is that the key2 and the data1 in the same line.
so i can use the function of pd.merge(xxx, on = 'key2').
this  really is a bug bug !!!!